# Pandas: Flatten dict values in DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

I've come across this problem very often now: I've got a nested dict (typically from an API / JSON payload) and need to flatten in for consumption as tabular data.

Example:

```json
invoices = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'currency': 'GBP',
        'lines': [
            {'line_id': 1, 'product': 'pencils', 'quantity': 100, 'price': 20},
            {'line_id': 2, 'product': 'erasers', 'quantity': 50, 'price': 10}
        ]
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'currency': 'USD',
        'lines': [
            {'line_id': 1, 'product': 'TV', 'quantity': 2, 'price': 800}
        ]
    }
]
```

`pd.DataFrame(invoices)` gives me a DataFrame with two lines, i.e. one per invoice. I can expand that to a per-line DataFrame as `pd.DataFrame(invoices).explode('lines')`, but then I have `dict`s in the `lines` column. How do I split/explode those `dict` keys into DataFrame columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A refinement to my previous answer.  This one retains the identifying columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(invoices).explode('lines')
df.apply(lambda x: x[['id','currency']].append(pd.Series(x['lines'])), axis=1)
```

Which delivers:

```
   id currency  line_id  product  quantity  price
0   1      GBP        1  pencils       100     20
0   1      GBP        2  erasers        50     10
1   2      USD        1       TV         2    800
```

Comment: That works well for just the line information -- but I lose the "header" fields, i.e. `id` and `currency`, and I don't see an obvious way of joining those back in, as each invoice can have different numbers of lines. Any other ideas how to solve that with standard pandas?

Comment: @EliasMi You are right.  I updated my answer which should directly answer the question.

Comment: Clever use of append, thank you! I hadn't realised how good Pandas was at keeping index values, even on operations like explode - that's useful to know!

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that the latest version of pandas allows [custom accessors](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/extending.html), which you can use to make this possible:

```py
# create per-line dataframe, as in the question
df = pd.DataFrame(invoices).explode('lines')

pd.concat([
    df.drop(columns=['lines']),  # remove nested column
    df['lines'].dict.explode()   # add flattened columns
], axis=1)
```

In order to be able to do this, you first need to define the `.dict` accessor:

```py
@pd.api.extensions.register_series_accessor('dict')
class DictAccessor:
    def __init__(self, pandas_obj):
        self._obj = pandas_obj
        
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._obj.apply(curried.get(key))
    
    def explode(self):
        return self._obj.apply(pd.Series)
```

This accessor also allows you to access individual keys in the `dict`, e.g.:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(invoices).explode('lines')

# total quantity across all invoices
df['lines'].dict['quantity'].sum()

# total cost per invoice
df.groupby('id').apply(lambda group: group['lines'].dict['price'].sum())
```

Comment: Very interesting.  Where is `curried` defined?  (from  `return self._obj.apply(curried.get(key))`)

Comment: That's from the [toolz](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) library -- sorry I use that so often, I sometimes forget I do :)